# Trying to add sound effect in as3 event listener function

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to add a laser sound effect when I am pressing spacebar. So far I haven't managed to figure out how to do it within this function.

```
        private function gameAddedToStage(evt: Event):void
        {
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyDownHandler);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,keyUpHandler);
        }   

        private function keyDownHandler(evt:KeyboardEvent):void

        {
            if (evt.keyCode == 32) //mellanslag
            {
                //Fire laser
                fireBullet = true;


            }
            else if (evt.keyCode == 37)
            {
                //Move player left
                moveX = -1;
            }
            else if (evt.keyCode == 39)
            {
                //Move player right
                moveX = 1;
            }

        }
```

Comment: What actually goes wrong? Please edit your question to give more information.

Comment: The problem is i don't know if I should add the sound event inside this function or make it a seperate function for the sound.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach of this problem would be to create a SoundManager which would handle the sounds, and that SoundManager would have a "playSound" function or something like that. So you could call it like `SoundManager.playSound("bullet_fire");`

Writing such SoundManager is not for beginners, rather intermediate of semi-pro. Check some tutorials or download a soundmanager class from the net.